# Can I force a PC to use the cached copy of offline files even when online?

Tags: windows-7, offline-files

We've been having some issues with the speed of opening large assembly drawings in Solidworks.  Because we keep our files on the network, its speed (1Gb) limits the speed of open and save.  We've looked into a document management packages and faster ethernet but at this point their cost is rather prohibitive.  So instead I got this crazy idea to use Windows Offline files.  But that would only work if there was a way to force the PC/User to always use the cached copy of the offline files even when the PC is online.  Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Set the network folder in question to "Work Offline":

From Microsoft's [Windows help site](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/working-with-network-files-when-you-are-offline):

> Open the network folder that contains the files you have made available offline, and then, on the toolbar, click Work offline. This button appears only if you have already made this folder available offline.
>
> When you are finished working with the files offline and want to begin working with the files in the network folder again, click Work online on the toolbar. This will sync any changes you have made offline with the files on the network.